# Transcoding streams with nginx ffmpeg problem

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg

I have 2 `nginx` servers

I have transcode ( `iptv` channels ) from server 1 to server 2

this is my `ffmpeg` code in ( `nginx.conf` ) server 1

```
exec_static /usr/bin/ffmpeg  -i http://iptv.channel.link.ts -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=256:144  -preset:v ultrafast -acodec aac -strict -2 -ab 64k -ar 44100 -f flv "rtmp://server2:1935/rtmp/channel1";
```

every thing is ok

but when I play the output `m3u8` channel

`http://server2:8080/streamshls/channel1/index.m3u8`

1 - it started slow
2 - it stops every 5 s and play again

what is the wrong thing?

I am sorry for my language because I am Arabic